# layout width not growing for all scenarios. I get top row full width (not desired) or have timestamp cut off if the text below gets smaller

Tags: android, layout

This is what I require.
[image: Required output]
But I end up having full width used due to **alignParentRight=true** or the timestamp gets cut off during my experiments.

How I get the output is like this.

[image]

Here is my code.Please see layout which works only if text is smaller than top row. if the text goes big, the icon and timestamp doesnt get aligned to the width of text, appropriately...couldnt get it working...

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <View
        android:id="@+id/divider"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/margin_10"
        android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/margin_10"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/margin_10"
        android:background="@color/colorDarkGrey"
        android:visibility="gone" />

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/checkbox_layout_id"
        android:layout_width="35dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/status_layt_id"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/status_layt_id"
        android:background="@android:color/darker_gray"
        android:visibility="visible">

        <CheckBox
            android:id="@+id/checkbox_id"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true" />

    </RelativeLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/checkbox_layout_id"
        android:paddingTop="8dp">

        <!--chat message holder-->
        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/chat_message_holder"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/status_lyt_id"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@drawable/chat_white_bg_rounded_corner"
                android:minWidth="130dp"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <!--header-->
                 <!--<include layout="@layout/adapter_comment_message_header"></include>-->

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:visibility="visible"
                    android:orientation="horizontal">

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/who_sent_id"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:fontFamily="sans-serif"
                        android:text="Directors name"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="12dp"
                        android:textColor="#696969"
                        android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
                        android:textSize="14sp" />
                    <!--<LinearLayout-->
                    <!--android:layout_width="wrap_content"-->
                    <!--android:layout_height="wrap_content">-->

                    <ImageView
                        android:id="@+id/status_message_id"
                        android:layout_width="16dp"
                        android:layout_height="16dp"
                        android:layout_marginRight="4dp"
                        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/timestamp_id"
                        android:src="@drawable/chat_svg_not_reached_ic"
                        android:tint="#696969" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/timestamp_id"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                        android:layout_gravity="right"
                        android:fontFamily="sans-serif"
                        android:gravity="right"
                        android:text="10:12 pm"
                        android:textColor="#696969"
                        android:textSize="14sp"
                        android:textStyle="normal" />
                    <!--</LinearLayout>-->
                 </LinearLayout>

                <!--content body-->
                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="12dp"
                    android:orientation="vertical"
                    android:paddingBottom="8dp"
                    android:paddingRight="12dp"
                    android:paddingTop="0dp">

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/message_tv_id"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:fontFamily="sans-serif"
                        android:padding="0dp"
                        android:text="SomeSomeSomeSomeSome.."
                        android:textColor="#D8000000"
                        android:textSize="18sp"
                        android:visibility="visible" />
                 </LinearLayout>
            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
    </RelativeLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: post some code please

Comment: @Nisarg new to this...so trying to post here..

Comment: its alright show us your layout xml file

Answer (score 0):

Try this layout instead of yours.Hope it will work for you

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="80dp"
android:orientation="horizontal">

<View
    android:id="@+id/divider"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="10dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:background="10dp"
    android:visibility="gone" />

<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/checkbox_layout_id"
    android:layout_width="55dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@android:color/darker_gray"
    android:visibility="visible">

    <CheckBox
        android:id="@+id/checkbox_id"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true" />

</RelativeLayout>

<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/chat_message_holder"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/who_sent_id"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="12dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
        android:fontFamily="sans-serif"
        android:text="Directors name"
        android:textColor="#696969"
        android:textSize="14sp" />


    <!--<LinearLayout-->
    <!--android:layout_width="wrap_content"-->
    <!--android:layout_height="wrap_content">-->

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/status_message_id"
        android:layout_width="16dp"
        android:layout_height="16dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="4dp"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/who_sent_id"
        android:tint="#696969" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/timestamp_id"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="left"
        android:fontFamily="sans-serif"
        android:gravity="right"
        android:text="10:12 pm"
        android:textColor="#696969"
        android:textSize="14sp"
        android:textStyle="normal"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/message_layout" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginLeft="12dp"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:paddingBottom="8dp"
        android:id="@+id/message_layout"
        android:layout_below="@+id/who_sent_id"
        android:paddingRight="12dp"
        android:paddingTop="0dp">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/message_tv_id"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:fontFamily="sans-serif"
            android:padding="0dp"
            android:text="SomeSomeSome.."
            android:textColor="#D8000000"
            android:textSize="18sp"
            android:visibility="visible" />
    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Please see I got following result(image) for 3 scenarios:
1) overlapping first row when name goes big
2) when second row (text) grows, the image doesnt stay close to text. I have tinkered this part before and its not easy for me..

Image below:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r5Sfs.png)

Answer (score 0):

Appreciate those who tried to help me. Weight is the only elastic method if we want to grow something directly based on another. Modified a sample posted by someone and it works perfectly fine. No matter which abcd grows, top or bottom,the clock icon and 1111111 will elastically adjust towards right

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/chat_message_holder"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/chat_white_bg_rounded_corner"
    android:orientation="vertical">
    <!--chat message holder-->

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <TextView
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz">
        </TextView>
        <ImageButton
            android:src="@drawable/chat_svg_not_reached_ic"
            android:layout_width="16dp"
            android:layout_height="16dp">
        </ImageButton>
        <TextView
            android:text="1111111"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        </TextView>
    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <TextView
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="abcdefghi">
        </TextView>

    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```